# Solving a PDE given a specific curve and condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following PDE:  $$-3U_x+4U_y=0$$ where $U=3x$ on curve $y=x+1$.

First we invoke the method of characteristics:  $$\frac{dx}{-3}=\frac{dy}{4}=\frac{dU}{0}.$$  From this we get $c_1=\frac{x}{3}+\frac{y}{4}$ and $U(x,y)=c_2$.  So $F(c_1)=c_2$ or $F(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{y}{4})=u(x,y)$.

Applying the condition, we know that $3x=u(x,x+1)=F(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x+1}{4})=F(\frac{x+3}{12}).$  So $F(\frac{x+3}{12})=3x.$  This is now where I'm stuck.

Comment: $U=3x$ so $U_x$ is just 3?  What do you mean by $U=3x$?

Comment: Right.  I'm not sure how to incorporate that and the curve y=x+1 into the whole situation.

Comment: If you already know what U is then what are you solving for?

Comment: Just $U_y$?  Did I work twice as hard trying to find $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: @mathematician I don't know what U is, it's a condition attached to the problem

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of  $-3U_x+4U_y=0$

obviously is $U(x,y)=F(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{y}{4}) \space$ where $F$ is any derivable function.

I don't understand what you mean "incorporate the curve". If you are talking of a boundary condition on the curve $y=x+1$, please, make clear what is the boundary condition.

With the condition  $U(x,y=x+1)=3x\space$ one have to find a function $F\space$ so that 
$$F(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x+1}{4})=3x$$
$$F(\frac{7x}{12}+\frac{1}{4})=3x$$
It is easy to see that the equality is obtained witth a function $F(X)=aX+b$ where $a=\frac{36}{7}$ and $b=-\frac{36}{7} \frac{1}{4}$ because :
$$\frac{36}{7}(\frac{7x}{12}+\frac{1}{4})-\frac{9}{7}=3x$$
As a consequence, the final result is :
$$U(x,y)=\frac{36}{7}(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{y}{4})-\frac{9}{7}$$

Comment: The question posed simply said subject to the conditiln u(x,0)=3x and the curve y=x+1.

Comment: If the condition is $U(x,o)=3x$, the condition is set on the curve $y=0$, not on $y=x+1$. And this implies $U(x,y)=3x+\frac{9}{4}y$. Sorry, I continue to not understand your wording "and the curve $y=x+1$ "

Comment: Sorry, I kept haphazardly reading the question.  I have made the appropriate correction.

Comment: Well, I suppose that I understand the bounding condition now. The corresponding result is added to my previous answer.